# How to Focus Button on press top bottom left rigth key in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, controller, remote-control, remotecontrolevent

How to Focus Button on press top bottom left right key in HTML?

I want to write Web App.

I want to the Web App can run on smart TV and any device.

They maybe only use controller.

But, I try controller control my Web App.

The controller top bottom left rigth key cannot focus my App button.

E.g.

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="b1">b1</button><button id="b2">b2</button><button id="b3">b3</button>
<br>
<button id="b4">b4</button><button id="b5">b5</button><button id="b6">b6</button>
<br>
<button id="b7">b7</button><button id="b8">b8</button><button id="b9">b9</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If this time focus b5 button.

I want to press "top" key it will focus b2.

I want to press "bottom" key it will focus b8.

I want to press "left" key it will focus b4.

I want to press "right" key it will focus b6.

Answer (score 0):

You must set tabindex of the button tabindex=-1
then you must call the method "focus" for the button element

example:
html: `<button id="myBtn" tabindex="-1">click me</button>`

JavaScirpt: `document.getElementById('myBtn').focus()`